# Как перенести текст который не влезает в инлайн кнопке на новую строку в кнопке?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Код генерации клавиатуры

```
def services_list_keyboard(language):
localization = load_localization(language)
kb = []
for item in localization['services_list']['list']:
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=item['title'], callback_data=item['value'])
    kb.append([button])

keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=kb)
return keyboard
```

Фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно же, использовать символ новой строки `\n`

```
button_text = "Первая строка\nВторая строка"
```

Но это вам не поможет.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

TOKEN = 'Token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_inline_keyboard(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Первая строка\nВторая строка\nТретья  строка\nЧетвертая строка\nПятая строка", callback_data='btn1'))
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Шестая строка", callback_data='btn2'))
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Очень длинный текст, который не\n помещается на одной строке", callback_data='btn3'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите один из вариантов:", reply_markup=keyboard)

bot.polling()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перенести строки как видите можно, но увеличить этим его объём - увы никак.

Единственное что могу вам предложить - это написать варианты ответов в тексте самого сообщения, а в кнопках поставить А, Б, В, 1, 2, 3...